# Oracle select column which does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

lets say I have a table Called Table with few columns.
In SELECT stetement I want to add column, which does not exist anywhere lets call it NonExistantClmn, which rows would be all the same value for example 0. Is there a good way to do this only within a select query? Or I rather create some temporary table and join with it?

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Value1 | Name1 |
| Value2 | Name2 |

Expected select output:

| ID | Name | NonExistantclmn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | Name1 | 0 |
| Value2 | Name2 | 0 |

I was thinking Bout joining with temp table but maybe theres a better way to do create that column

Comment: You may use any [expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Expressions.html#GUID-68789A5C-B142-496F-ADEE-837F75F95B2B) (something that evaluates to a value) in your `select` list. Constant is expression also

Answer (score 2):

You can just add further columns to your result and give them an alias:

```
SELECT id, name, 0 AS NonExistantclmn
FROM yourtable;
```

To think out of the box: If you change your mind and want to provide different values in this column, depending on a condition based on another column, use `CASE WHEN`.

For example:

```
SELECT id, name, 0 AS NonExistantclmn,
CASE WHEN name IS NULL 
THEN 'NameMissing' 
ELSE 'NameThere' END AS NamePresence
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Thabk you. Alias was right under my nose. But I completely forgot about it!